# How can I raise an error if an environment does not contain the symbol when using the dollar operator?

Tags: r

This code

```
e <- new.env()
print(e$notexistent)
```

gives NULL. I want it to raise an error (as in a stop()). Is it possible in R 3.5 or above?

Comment: Maybe `stopifnot(exists("notexistent", e))`?

Comment: @AllanCameron That's not what I meant. I want it to happen automatically. That is, if I try to access a symbol that is not there, it's clearly an error. I don't expect it to give me NULL so that I can try to execute a NULL instead of a function.

Comment: are you asking if there is a setting to change R's default behaviour here?

Comment: you could access the element using `get` function instead of the `$` function. ie `get("nonexistent", e)`

Comment: or maybe use `with(e, nonexistent)`, this yields an error if object doesn't exist in `e` but won't if it exists

Comment: @Onyambu I want to use the dollar. I am using it as a scope operator. My point is that there's no reason to return a value from an environment if the value is not there.

Comment: @jay.sf This language is broken beyond repair. I am trying to mitigate its damage by having a module system closer to the python one, but I want to call routines that I defined inside isolated environments, rather than throwing everything in the global environment and hope that there are no conflicts.

Comment: Apparently, that is how R internals work. `$` will give `NULL` if applied to an environment that does not contain the variable.

Comment: @Onyambu **throws chair**. Thanks

Comment: you could use if statements to get around this. Since you wrote that you are trying to have a module system closer to the python one, in the python one, do you have an environment or a class?

Comment: @StefanoBorini Since you mentioned wanting a module system, check out my corresponding project https://github.com/klmr/modules, in particular the new API: https://github.com/klmr/modules/issues/129 … rather than duplicate the effort, maybe we could pool resources. And, more on the subject: using my code, `foo$bar` raises an error if `bar` is not defined. You can do that yourself by overriding `$` (but only for custom classes unfortunately!).

Comment: @KonradRudolph oh my god you are my lord and saviour.